# Why is the $ (list subset, dollar notation) not allowed in dplyr::mutate expressions?

Tags: r, dplyr

The following snippet:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(col1=rep(1:5, c(3,3,2,1,1)))
df <- df %>%
     mutate(rle=sequence(rle(col1)$lengths))
```

fails with

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): invalid subscript type 'closure'

when using `dplyr 0.5.0`. This seems to be a limitation of the non standard evaluation of arguments `dplyr::mutate` since

```
df$rle <- with(df, sequence(rle(col1)$lengths))
```

works as expected (and `with` also uses NSE, and the expression has `$` also) producing:

```
col1 rle 
   1   1 
   1   2
   1   3
   2   1
   2   2
   2   3
   3   1
   3   2
   4   1
   5   1
```

Can anyone explain why the first construct is not allowed within `dplyr::mutate`?

I know the problem is the `$lengths` since `mutate(rle=sequence(rle(col1)[["lengths"]])` works.  From above it seems that `$name` notation won't work but `[["name"]]`is ok.

Can anyone explain how the expression is transformed inside the `dplyr::mutate` to produce that error?

Comment: The problem here is the `$lengths`. `rle2 <- function(x) rle(x)$lengths
; df %>%  mutate(rle = sequence(rle2(col1)))` does work. But a question of the form 'name any limitations' is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: You could use `sequence(rle(col1)[["lengths"]]` instead within `mutate`.

Comment: Well, I figured out that it was the `$length` bit, but what are the rules? I mean what kind of constructs are allowed and which one are not?  Maybe the question is really what subset of expressions are allowed inside  a `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: In principle anything that returns a vector of length 1 or length n should be allowed. This is probably an unintentional consequence of the internal trickery that `dplyr` is doing. Perhaps report as an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues)?

Comment: Submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2125) to `dplyr` project.